# Remove ALL CAP text words and colon

Tags: regular-expression

I would like to be able to remove words using Notepad++'s Search (and Replace) that are all upper case followed by a colon - searching for and then removing both the uppercase word and colon from the line...example:

```
BRYAN: What happened? OK Judy, Is it true?
CONNOR: Well... he is done.
BRYAN: That much is true.
```

I believe the following expression will select ALL CAP WORDS, but need to add the option to include the colon with the word.

```
\b[A-Z]\w+[A-Z]\b
```

Anyone with a suggestion to revise the above line to select the colon as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to ignore the Notepad++ part of the question and focus on the regular expression you've supplied and the associated requirement.

It looks like a PCRE, since it uses `\w`. In any RE style you can use a literal `:` as itself. But the basis for the underlying RE is still wrong so it needs reformulating from scratch

- Anchor to start of line `^`
- Match one or more uppercase characters `[[:upper:]]+`
- Match a colon `:`
- Follow with zero or more spaces `\s*`

The result is this

```
^[[:upper:]]+:\s*
```

Your own expression would match words of three characters or more, where the first and last characters were capitals. So `BeD` would match, as would `LONGEST`, but `JO` or `done` would not. Notice also that neither your solution nor mine will handle names (words) containing punctuation such as `O'NEILL` or `CHOLMONDELEY SMYTHE`